# Need to wipe hard drive Ubuntu 12.10 to put Windows

Tags: 12.10, windows-xp

My dad had a blank hard drive on which I installed Ubuntu because it was easier than getting windows. Some WiFi drivers will not install. My dad only uses it for email, Craiglist, and chat on Facebook, so he doesn't care what OS he has as long as he can go online. I have the XP disk.

When I type `sudo fdisk -l` in the terminal i get

/dev/sda1   *        2048   114300927    57149440   83  Linux

/dev/sda2       114302974   117229567     1463297    5  Extended

/dev/sda5       114302976   117229567     1463296   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Then i type `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=device bs=1M` and nothing happens. How do I wipe the whole hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an Ubuntu question per se. Nevertheless when you install XP, it should give you an option to completely overwrite what is currently on it. You don't have to remove Ubuntu first.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then you have a HDD which has a corrupted OS. Plug it into some other computer which is working correctly and format it. Then you will be able to do anything.